# How to tell BabelJS not to override this

Tags: webpack, babeljs

Babel is replacing `this` with `void 0` how can I prevent this behavior?

I have this code:

```
((parent)=>{
  parent.something = {}
})(this)
```

With babel it renders like

```
(function (parent) {
  parent.something = {}
})(void 0);
```

I need this

```
(function (parent) {
  parent.something = {}
})(this);
```

I know that I can use `self` but this is not the same in all cases

Comment: Babel will replace `this` with `void 0` if `this` is undefined.
In es6 modules, the top-level value of `this` is undefined, not the `window` object.

Comment: If that's the case, you should be able to fix it by editing your babel configuration (.babelrc or similar) to (assuming you're using babel-preset-env): { "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", {modules: false} ] } see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#modules for details

Comment: @krisaoe The documentation says something the code says it's wrong. I got this error:
`Using removed Babel 5 option: .modules - Use the corresponding module transform plugin in the `plugins` option. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#modules`

Answer (score 5):

In the `babelrc` file or your bundler config set babel with:

`presets: [["@babel/preset-env", { modules: false }]]`

Note the double brackets, reason [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9679#issuecomment-472640723)